# Loop one extra row every 5 loops. Determined by speed of player

Tags: php, while-loop

I'm trying to figure out how to make the player, that has 2 more speed than the opponent. To attack one extra attack every 5 hits. But I can't come up with a good method to calculate this.

```
<?php
$monster_speed = 10;
$player_speed = 12;
$turn = mt_rand(0,1);
$hitnum = 1;

while($hitnum <= 15) {
    if ($turn % 2 == 0) {
        echo $hitnum. ". Monster attacked<br>";
        $hitnum++;
        $turn++;
    } else {
        echo $hitnum. ". Player attacked<br>";
        $hitnum++;
        $turn++;
    }
}
?>
```

**Output now:**

```
1. Player attacked
2. Monster attacked
3. Player attacked
4. Monster attacked
5. Player attacked
6. Monster attacked
7. Player attacked
8. Monster attacked
9. Player attacked
10. Monster attacked
11. Player attacked
12. Monster attacked
13. Player attacked
14. Monster attacked
15. Player attacked
```

**Goal (if player speed is 12 and enemy speed is 10 for example):**

```
1. Player attacked
2. Monster attacked
3. Player attacked
4. Monster attacked
5. Player attacked
6. Monster attacked
7. Player attacked
8. Monster attacked
9. Player attacked
10. Player attacked
11. Monster attacked
12. Player attacked
13. Monster attacked
14. Player attacked
15. Monster attacked
```

Comment: Interesting question. My question to you would be, where are the monster and player speeds in regards to the loop? Currently, it will switch back and forth and the speeds have no bearing. Rather than using a hard coded divisible by 2, you can try to add the speed of one or the other in some sort of operation.

Answer (score 2):

See if this works out a bit better. It probably needs more calculating, but maybe the approach may give you some ideas. If not, not a problem, I'll retract it! I should mention, this is an asymmetrical algorithm in that the hits will be skewed towards whomever hits first so in this instance it could be `13 vs 7` OR `12 vs 8` point outcome:

```
<?php
// this just sees what the mathematical diff is between the p1 and p2
// also taking into consideration your iterations (length)
function offset_hit($pspeed = 0,$mspeed = 0,$length = 0)
    {
        $diff   =   ($pspeed - $mspeed);
        return ($diff != 0)? floor(($length / $diff)) : false;
    }
// This just sees how many more times a player should strike per
// iteration
function disparity($p1 = 0,$p2 = 0)
    {
        // I just floor rounded this but you could make this more 
        // complex to determine value...
        return ($p1 >= $p2)? floor($p1 / $p2) : floor($p2 / $p1);
    }
// Create a function to both output and return the results
// This allows for future hit-point processing...etc.
function FightToTheDeath($p1,$p2,$settings = false) {
        // The length (loops)
        $length =   (!empty($settings['length']) && is_numeric($settings['length']))? $settings['length'] : 10;
        $hitnum =   (!empty($settings['hitnum']) && is_numeric($settings['hitnum']))? $settings['hitnum'] : 1;
        $turn   =   mt_rand(0,1);
        // Percentage difference in overall character vs character
        $disp   =   disparity($p1,$p2);
        // This checks at what interval the disparity will occur
        $offset =   offset_hit($p2,$p1,$length);

        $start  =   $i = 1;
        while($hitnum <= $length) {
                if ($turn % 2 == 0) {
                        // I have the turn taking based off the player so there
                        // are some ifs here for monster
                        if(($offset != 0) || ($start == 1) || !$offset) {
                                $order[]    =   "m";
                                echo $hitnum. ". Monster attacked<br>";
                            }
                    }
                else {
                        $order[]    =   "p";
                        echo $hitnum. ". Player attacked<br>";
                    }
                // Calculate the extra hits here.
                if(($i == str_replace("-","",$offset)) || $disp > 1) {
                        // This is how many extra a turn character can attack
                        // This takes into account they already struck once
                        $disparity  =   (($disp - 1) <= 0)? 1 : $disp-1;
                        // Loop through remaining hits
                        for($a = 1; $a <= $disparity; $a++) {
                                $order[]    =   ($offset < 0)? "m" : "p";
                                echo ($offset < 0)? "+Speed. Monster attacked<br>" : "+Speed. Player attacked<br>";
                            }
                        // Rest iterator counter.   
                        $i  =   0;
                    }
                // You only need these once.
                $hitnum++;
                $turn++;
                $i++;
            }

        return (!empty($order))? $order : array();
    }

?>
```

**TO USE:**

```
<?php
// Include the above functions...

// Monster's speed
$mSpeed =   15;
// Player's speed
$pSpeed =   10;
// Write out the value, but also assign scores
$playByplay =   FightToTheDeath($mSpeed,$pSpeed,array("length"=>15,"hitnum"=>1));
// Count how many times each player is hit
// You can now feed this into a new function that tallies up
// total damage and such and such...
$scorecard  =   array_count_values($playByplay);

print_r($scorecard);
?>
```

**This set of prefs gives you:**

> 1.Monster attacked
>   2.Player attacked
>   3.Monster attacked
>   **+Speed. Monster attacked**
>   4.Player attacked
>   5.Monster attacked
>   6.Player attacked
>   **+Speed. Monster attacked**
>   7.Monster attacked
>   8.Player attacked
>   9.Monster attacked
>   **+Speed. Monster attacked**
>   10.Player attacked
>   11.Monster attacked
>   12.Player attacked
>   **+Speed. Monster attacked**
>   13.Monster attacked
>   14.Player attacked
>   15.Monster attacked
>   **+Speed. Monster attacked**

```
Array
(
    [m] => 13
    [p] => 7
)
```

The outcome is not 100% like you are looking at however, you can likely create the same thing by using `continue` in the loop. You can fiddle around with it.

Answer (score 0):

```
$monster_speed = 10;
    $player_speed = 12;

    $turn = mt_rand(0,1);
    $monsterHitCount = 0;
    $playerHitCount = 0;
    $hitnum = 1;

    while($hitnum <= 15) {
        if ($turn % 2 == 0) {
            echo $hitnum. ". Monster attacked<br>";
            $hitnum++;
            $turn++;
            $monsterHitCount ++;
            if($monsterHitCount % 5 === 0 && $monster_speed > $player_speed) {
                echo $hitnum. ". Monster attacked<br>";
                $hitnum++;
            }
        } else {
            echo $hitnum. ". Player attacked<br>";
            $hitnum++;
            $turn++;
            $playerHitCount ++;
            if($playerHitCount % 5 === 0 && $monster_speed < $player_speed) {
                echo $hitnum. ". Player attacked<br>";
                $hitnum++;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Well this does not take the speed of the player and monster into account. This will only print an extra attack evey 5 loops for whoever has the highest speed. For example. If monster has 10 speed and player has 15. Then player should add an attack every 2nd attack.

Comment: This does exactly what you asked. If you wanted the attacks to be dynamic according to speed you should have specified that because that is something totally different.

Comment: Yes you're right, i'm sorry if i wasnt clear enough. But that was what i was trying to explain!

Comment: So if I understand you correctly the two attack each other every other turn. If one has a speed between 2 and 4 they would get an extra attack every fifth attack. and if they have a speed of 5 or greater they would attack with an extra attack every other attack?